# Fill row NaN value by comparing latest known value and first know before NaN row

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I really new to Python and Datascience.

I have a dataset with like 100K+ rows, i have two columns on this dataset.

The first one is a Datetime column, let's name it `A`, the last one is an Integer, let's name it `B`.

My Dataset is sorted by column A.

In my Dataset, some of `B` values are NaN.

I want to fill my NaN Values using by doing this:

For row i with NaN B value: 
    If (Latest none NaN B value before my row i - First none NaN B value after my row i) == 0 set B value of row i to "Latest none NaN B value before my row i"
    else set it to "Latest none NaN B value before my row i"-difference in seconds between column A of "Latest none NaN B value before my row i" and column A of my row i

Let me explain myself with an example:

My Dataset looks like this :

```
                     A     B
0  2019-03-13 08:12:20  10.0
1  2019-03-13 08:12:21   NaN
2  2019-03-13 08:12:22   NaN
3  2019-03-13 08:12:23  10.0
4  2019-03-13 08:12:24   NaN
5  2019-03-13 08:12:25   NaN
6  2019-03-13 08:12:26   7.0
```

At the end i want it to look like this:

```
                     A     B
0  2019-03-13 08:12:20  10.0
1  2019-03-13 08:12:21  10.0
2  2019-03-13 08:12:22  10.0
3  2019-03-13 08:12:23  10.0
4  2019-03-13 08:12:24   9.0
5  2019-03-13 08:12:25   8.0
6  2019-03-13 08:12:26   7.0
```

(Column B of row id=1) and (Column B of row id=2) are 10 because (Column B of row id=0)=(Column B of row id=3).
(Column B of row id=4) is 9 because (Column B of row id=3)=/=(Column B of row id=6) and (Column B of row id=3)-(time_diff(Column A of row id=3, Column A of row id=4)).

The best i could do is to set the NaN to the latest known value, but that's really not what i want to do.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ["2019-03-13 08:12:20", "2019-03-13 08:12:21", "2019-03-13 08:12:22", "2019-03-13 08:12:23", "2019-03-13 08:12:24", "2019-03-13 08:12:25"], 'B': [10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7]})
df['B'] = df['B'].replace({'B': {0: np.nan}}).ffill()
print(df)
```

You guys have any clean way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using the the [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) function -

```
df.interpolate(method ='linear', limit_direction ='forward')
```

which will attempt to fill in the data in the manner you are looking for if possible.
(it is not too effective with NaN values at the start and end of columns)

Comment: Thanks, it does the job ! Do you have any source where i can learn python and pandas for Datascience ?